# How to insert similar row twice in database using trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let me explain.

I have a trigger on table A that executes every time a table A has data inserted in it or data is updated.
Trigger copies the same data into "log" table B every time.

Now, I have request to add a specific row from table A into that "log" B table, in the same operation, but with one field changed.

Heres example:

Data that is inserted or updated into TABLE A

```
LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER = 1
CONTROL_STATUS = 'N'
ID = 1234
DEST_UNIT = 'ALL'

LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER = 2
CONTROL_STATUS = 'Y'
ID = 4321
DEST_UNIT = 'ALL'
```

Then a trigger fires and copies this data into log table B
Trigger goes like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_A
ON table_A
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO table_B(
    LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    CONTROL_STATUS,
    ID,
    DEST_UNIT)

SELECT(
    i.LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    i.CONTROL_STATUS,
    i.ID,
    i.DEST_UNIT)

FROM inserted i
```

This works fine as the row in table B is filled with the data

The requirement is to have that row inserted into table_B twice but with same data.

So result of original trigger is:

```
table_B
LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER  | CONTROL_STATUS | ID | DEST_UNIT
1  |  N  |  1234 | ALL
1  |  Y  |  4321 | ALL
```

What i need to achieve in the same insert/update;

```
table_B
LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER  | CONTROL_STATUS | ID | DEST_UNIT
1  |  N  |  1234 | ALL
1  |  N  |  1234 | APP <-- the duplicate row with different data in the field
1  |  Y  |  4321 | ALL
```

Essentially, I need to use the trigger to add the same row twice, but change one field on the second row..

I did try to use 2 separate triggers, and did try to write two insert statements in the same trigger, but it doesn't really work.

If I write trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_A
ON table_A
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO table_B(
    LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    CONTROL_STATUS,
    ID,
    DEST_UNIT)

SELECT(
    i.LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    i.CONTROL_STATUS,
    i.ID,
    i.DEST_UNIT)

FROM inserted i
END
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_B(
    LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    CONTROL_STATUS,
    ID,
    DEST_UNIT)

SELECT(
    i.LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    i.CONTROL_STATUS,
    i.ID,
    i.DEST_UNIT)

FROM inserted i
END
```

It works but it duplicates both rows and changes their "DEST_UNIT" to "APP"
Like this:

```
 LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER  | CONTROL_STATUS | ID | DEST_UNIT
1  |  N  |  1234 | ALL
1  |  N  |  1234 | APP 
1  |  Y  |  4321 | ALL
1  |  Y  |  4321 | APP
```

But if i change trigger to this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_A
ON table_A
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO table_B(
    LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    CONTROL_STATUS,
    ID,
    DEST_UNIT)

SELECT(
    i.LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    i.CONTROL_STATUS,
    i.ID,
    i.DEST_UNIT)

FROM inserted i
END
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_B(
    LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    CONTROL_STATUS,
    ID,
    DEST_UNIT)

SELECT(
    i.LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER,
    i.CONTROL_STATUS,
    i.ID,
    i.DEST_UNIT)

FROM inserted i WHERE i.ID = '1234'
END
```

Adding the WHERE in the end doesn't do anything, it just copies the original two rows.
Resulting again in:

```
LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER  | CONTROL_STATUS | ID | DEST_UNIT
1  |  N  |  1234 | ALL
1  |  Y  |  4321 | ALL
```

Sorry for the long code, just wanted to be as much informative as I can!
Thanks for help!

Comment: Please change the title word SAME to SIMILAR  for the row as they are NOT duplicates in ALL columns.  NOTE:  If they were duplicates in ALL columns, it would be very bad practice to insert 'SAME' row twice.  But it may be needed to insert SIMILAR ROW twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to generate two rows:

```
INSERT INTO table_B (LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER, CONTROL_STATUS, ID, DEST_UNIT)
    SELECT i.LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER, i.CONTROL_STATUS, i.ID, v.DEST_UNIT
    FROM inserted i CROSS APPLY
         (VALUES (v.DEST_UNIT), ('APP')) v(DEST_UNIT);
```

If you want this to be conditional, then add a `WHERE` clause.  I would probably use:

```
INSERT INTO table_B (LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER, CONTROL_STATUS, ID, DEST_UNIT)
    SELECT i.LEGACY_ROW_NUMBER, i.CONTROL_STATUS, i.ID, v.DEST_UNIT
    FROM inserted i CROSS APPLY
         (VALUES (v.DEST_UNIT),
                 (CASE WHEN ID = 1234 THEN 'APP' END)
         ) v(DEST_UNIT)
    WHERE v.DEST_UNIT IS NOT NULL;
```